# Find the trace of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $227\times227$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_{227}$, such that all the eigenvalues are distinct. What is the trace of $A$?

Comment: the diagonal matrix with distinct numbers on the diagonal fits the description

Comment: It is quite unlikely that this matrix is diagonalisable over $\Bbb F_{227}=\Bbb Z/227\Bbb Z$. If it is not, what do you mean by an eigenvalue? Most people would take them in an algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_{227}$; in any case the question cannot be given a definie answer without additional hypothesis.

Answer (score 4):

It can be anything you want. Let $E$ be the extension field $\mathbb{F}_{227^{227}}$ of the prime field $F=\mathbb{F}_{227}$. The trace mapping $tr: E\to F$ is surjective, so given any element $a\in F$ there exists an element $z_a\in E$ such that the linear transformation $T:x\mapsto z_a\cdot x$ from $E$ to $E$ has trace $a$.

The eigenvalues of the matrix of $T$ (w.r.t. to any basis) are the conjugates of $z_a$. As $z_a\notin F$, and there are no intermediate fields, those eigenvalues are distinct elements of $E$.

---

Edit: It is known that the polynomial $f_a(x)=x^{227}-x+1/a$ is irreducible over $F$ for any $a\in F^*$. The reciprocal of this polynomial 
$$
p_a(x)=ax^{227}f(1/x)=x^{227}-ax^{226}+a
$$
is thus also irreducible, and has $-a$ as the coefficient of the degree $226$ term. Thus any zero of $p_a(x)$ can take the role of $z_a$ above.

Comment: Nice. I think your argument is more decisive than what I was going to add to mine.

Answer (score 1):

All answers given so far (except the one by Jyrki Lahtonen) are wrong, since they assume that eigenvalues must all live (and therefore fill up) the field $\Bbb F_{227}$. Nothing in the question gives that. Either the eigenvalues are taken (and all distinct) in an algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_{227}$, but very little can be said about their sum. Or only the eigenvalues that happen to lie in $\Bbb F_{227}$ are assumed to be distinct (but there could well be none of them at all), and there is even less to base a conclusion on.

Concretely, you can take your matrix to be the companion matrix of any unitary degree $227$ polynomial$~P$ you like, and the trace will be minus the subdominant coefficient of$~P$. Now it should be easy to fix that coefficient to any value you like, and still ensure that $P$ is irreducible and separable (the latter just means avoid the polynomials $X^{227}+a$); in that case $P$ will be relatively prime to $P'$, and hence without multiple roots.

As a curiosity, replacing $p=227$ by $p=2$, the trace does have to be$~1$ (if it were$~0$, the characteristic polynomial would be $X^2+a$ which has a double root $a\in\Bbb F_2$).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: ***If*** you happen to know that all the eigenvalues are elements of $\Bbb Z_{227},$ then all you have to do is take the sum of the eigenvalues. Otherwise, as Jyrki and Marc point out, there's no way to know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then you want the sum of **all** the elements in $\,\Bbb Z_{227}\;$ , but for any odd prime $\,p\,$:

$$\sum_{a\in\Bbb Z_p} a=\frac{p(p-1)}2=0\pmod p$$

Comment: Actually, there is no need for $p$ to be prime. It suffices that $p$ is odd.

Comment: Just assumed that...as otherwise the answer's open.